# Laravel 5.3 relationship issue, returns more than 1

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

I have a problem with a query.
I have 3 models: Course,MainTask and Task.
Course has many MainTasks and a MainTask has many Tasks.

I have the users current MainTask stored in the database, i want to select the Course with the main task and tasks where the users current main task and course is.

My attempt:

```
$tasks=Course::where('id',$current->current_course)->whereHas('mainTask', function ($q) use ($current)
    {
        $q->where('id',$current->current_main_task_id);
    })->with('mainTask.task')->first();
```

But this returns all the main tasks not just 1.

```
class Course extends Model
{
    public function mainTask () {
        return $this->hasMany('App\MainTask');
    }
}

class MainTask extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    public function task () {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Task');
    }

    public function course () {
        return $this->belongsTo('Courses');
    }
}



class Task extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    public function mainTask () {
        return $this->belongsTo('MainTask');
    }
}
```

Any tips?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looks like loading the relationships from your mainTask would be easiest:

```
MainTask::with('course', 'task')->find($current->current_main_task_id);
```

Will load 1 main task with it's course and all of it's tasks

Comment: forgot to mention i have the current course stored and i need to check that too

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? I don't understand the context.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $tasks=Course::where('id',$current->current_course)
        ->with(['mainTask' => function ($q) use ($current)
    {
        return $q->where('id',$current->current_main_task_id);
    },'mainTask.task'])->first();
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to go with the code so others can learn how it works